# Combining two strings

Tags: objective-c, string, nsstring

I don't know how to combine two `NSString`s. I've a label, `rohstoffe` and want to set its text with two strings, but the label only shows the last string.

Why?

Here is my code:

```
NSString *n = @"A";
NSString *m = @"B";
self.rohstoffe.text = (@"%d und %d", n, m);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
self.rohstoffe.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ und %@", n, m];
```

`%@` is for strings and pointers `%i` and `%d` are for integers and `%f` is used for floats and double. This should cover you for most stuff. These are the same symbols used for NSLog.
A full list can be found [here](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSLog)

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning only the first parameter of your expression. Try this:

```
self.rohstoffe.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d und %d", n, m];
```

Comment: n and m are strings, so the format string should be `@"%@ und %@"`